# Problem using toggleclass to change the span of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, blueprint-css

I am using blueprint CSS framework. I have an article spanning 24 cols but I trying to use jQuery toggleclass (`onclick`) to reduce it to 20 cols and show the buttons for actions in the remaining 4 cols.

```
$("div").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("span-24"); 
   $(this).toggleClass("span-20");
  });
});
```

I have more than one div so I use each, but it does not work.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you're after:

```
$("div").toggle(function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "span-24");
}, function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "span-20");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the click event to all divs without the `each` loop. Also, you can use the `:gt()` [greater-than selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and then `toggle()` [the visibility](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) of those spans

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).find("span:gt(19)").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't want to toggle classes on all `divs` you have, rather just the one with content
2. you can even simplify this code more:

   $('#toggler').click(function(){
     $('#content').toggleClass('span-20 span-24');
   });

the `#toggler.click()` is just one of events that can run the `toggleClass()`, in your HTML it could be onload or whatever:

```
$('#content').toggleClass('span-20 span-24'); //main code (and all of it, too)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/hhMFs/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$("div").click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("span-20 span-24"); });
```